# Reordering tableviewcells, white "bar" on the RIGHT side

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm struggling with a problem, that i cant seem to find a solution to.

Just to illustrate real quick what the problem is, i've added some images:

This is what my tableview does when adding images, taken in portrait mode:

[image: PortraitImage]

As you can see, it adds this white bar on the right side of the imageview.. The imageview in the tableviewcell, has constraints to margins - its like the reordercontrol takes up some space, that the imageview can't use.

The strange thing is, that when I add a image taken in landscape mode, the imageview acts like i want it to - as you can see here:

[image: LangscapeImage]

I cant really figure out whats the problem, or - I know the problem is that the tableview is in editingmode, because when I set that to false, the problem is solved - but then I'm not able to reorder my tableview cells :)

Here's some relevant code:

tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
```

I've tried to see if I could remove the subview for the reordercontrol like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    for view in cell.subviews {
        print(view.description)
        if view.description.containsString("UITableViewCellReorderControl"){
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

with no luck.. It just removes the reordercontrol (the three lines), and the white bar is still there..

My imageview's contentMode is set to AspectFill in storyboard.

Any suggestions? :-)

Comment: What is your image view's contentMode?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong - its set to Aspect Fill in Storyboard :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with swapping out the tableView with a collectionView, and then added a gesture to reorder the cells :) Thanks anyway..